# In google sheets is it possible create/embed a dropdown fillable table?

Tags: google-sheets

What I am trying to do is have a cell be the sum of a set of values that are from a table, and for the values of this table to be easily accessible/changeable from the near the cell. The issue is that I am using a premade google sheet that I cannot (and don't want to) change the formatting on.

**I was wondering if it was possible to embed a table within a cell or a nearby cell and have that cell display a sum. I was thinking similar to the dropdown menu where (if it is possible) to create a dropdown editable table.**

I don't have any experience with sheets or excel unfortunately so ideas are all I have. I know the summation is easy, I'm just wondering if its possible to have it easily accessible without changing the formatting.

Image 1: Current Formatting for Context[image]

So the tan miscellaneous cells display the sum of a simple table (Image 2):

[image]

For further context this is a sheet that a friend made for our tabletop game where he made a single miscellaneous cell for a bunch of bonuses. Basically what I'm trying to do is separate the bonuses back out and have their sum in the box. Also he will not work on the sheet anymore.

Here is a view only version of the sheet, feel free to make a copy and try things: [Current Personal Version of the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ORzBRTmKOkZ-sldeSnYBX0CdJudEF2gPc4GThgL4P4c/edit?usp=sharing)

Edit: The misc boxes I'm specifically talking about are L112-L167 and AQ112-AQ167.

Answer (score 0):

I answered:

> [Can the] *tan miscellaneous cells display the sum of a simple table (Image 2)*

1. Add a sheet in `Misc` where you will house your added data and use the same names in `Misc!A2:A20` as you have in the `'Character Sheet Template'!D112:D166` and `'Character Sheet Template'!AC112:AC166`
2. Use `SUM` with `INDEX` and `MATCH` in a formula to get the totals for each of the names from your table in `MISC`

##### Named Ranges

Naming the ranges makes the solution easier to follow.

- **char01**
  `'Character Sheet Template'!D112:D166`
  *This 1<sup>st</sup> range is named to dynamically generate the 1<sup>st</sup> half of the categories on our new `Misc` sheet and avoid typos.*
- **char02**
  `'Character Sheet Template'!AC112:AC166`
  *This 2<sup>nd</sup> range is also named to dynamically generate the 2<sup>nd</sup> half of the categories on our new `Misc` sheet and avoid typos.*
- **miscCategories**
  `Misc!A2:A39`
  *This is the column with the categories (generated from **char01** and **char02**) that we will match with*
- **miscData**
  `Misc!B2:E39`
  *This is all the new misc data that we want to sum if the category matches*

##### `1`   Create the table in sheet Misc

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ={"";FILTER(char01,LEN(char01)>0);FILTER(char02,LEN(char02)>0)} | Competence | Morale | Insight | Circumstance |

This pulls all the names from `char01` & `char02` and places them in in `miscCategories`

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

##### `2`   Put Formula in 'Character Sheet Template'

|  | D E F G H | I | J K | L M | N O | P Q | R S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 |  |  | Total | Ranks | Ability | Class | Misc. |
| 112 | Acrobatics | Dex | 2 |  | -5 |  | =sum(index(miscData,match(D112,miscCategories))) |

- In `'Character Sheet Template'!R112` you put `=sum(index(miscData,match(D112,miscCategories)))`
- The formula in `R112` can then  be pasted in `R115`, `R118`, `R121`, etc. all the way down.
- Similarly, in `'Character Sheet Template'!AQ112` you put
  `=sum(index(miscData,match(AC112,miscCategories)))`
- The formula in `AQ112` can then  be pasted in `AQ115`, `AQ118`, `AQ121`, etc. all the way down.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

##### Creating `miscCategories`

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ={"";FILTER(char01,LEN(char01)>0);FILTER(char02,LEN(char02)>0)} |

The formula in `'Misc'!A1` dynamically returns the following array for our category column

```
{ "", "Acrobatics", "Appraise", "Bluff", "Climb",
  "Craft", "Craft", "Diplomacy", "Disable Device",
  "Disguise", "Escape Artist", "Fly", "Handle Animal",
  "Heal", "Intimidate", "Knowledge (Arcana)",
  "Knowledge (Dungeoneering)", "Knowledge (Engineering)",
  "Knowledge (Geography)", "Knowledge (History)",
  "Knowledge (Local)", "Knowledge (Nature)",
  "Knowledge (Nobility)", "Knowledge (Planes)",
  "Knowledge (Religion)", "Linguistics", "Perception",
  "Perform", "Perform", "Profession", "Profession",
  "Ride", "Sense Motive", "Sleight of Hand",
  "Spellcraft", "Stealth", "Survival", "Swim",
  "Use Magic Device" }
```